# Manage domains and subdomains between multiples app engine/compute engine instances

Tags: subdomain, google-cloud-platform, domains

The question is simple. How can "distribute" domains and subdomains between app engine/compute engine in Google Cloud?
For example, I have the following domain:
**example.com**
I want to use the subdomain ***www*.example.com** to host static/dynamic web pages related to my company.
Buy another domain, for example, **application.com**, and here host a web application built in ASP.NET or another framework, I don't know.
Use the subdomain ***api*.example.com** to host a ASP.NET Core MVC/Web API application that handles all API requests (related to user data, for example if the application is a chat app) coming from **application.com** application.

*Summary*
Domain: **example.com**
Subdomains:
- **www.example.com** -> Host static/dynamic pages related to my company
- **api.example.com** -> Manage all users, databases, and has the API controllers

Domain: **application.com**
Subdomains:
- **www.application.com** -> Host chat app for example

How do I have to do it? Create multiple Google Cloud projects? Or multiple instances of App engine/Compute engine? And how can I "distribute" the domains and subdomains explained above

Comment: Assuming, you are asking about mapping the domains running on GAE, Yes, you will be able to use domain and  sub-domains with [custom domain mapping](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application),  then create DNS records for the domain to do anything  you want to do

Answer (score 1):

You're able to manage domains and subdomains between multiples App Engine/Compute Engine instances. It's quite broad question, but it general you can follow steps below:

1. Register domain names using [Google Domains](https://domains.google/) or other registrar.
2. Decide which DNS hosting you prefer: provided by registrar or [Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial).
3. (*in case of switching to Cloud DNS*) [Create new zones](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/zones) for your domains (you can follow [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart) for Cloud DNS).
4. (*in case of switching to Cloud DNS*) [Update name servers](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290309?hl=en) at the registrar side for each domain.
5. To determine how many projects you need have a look at the documentation [Creating and managing projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects) to find more details:

   > Google Cloud projects form the basis for creating, enabling, and using
   > all Google Cloud services including managing APIs, enabling billing,
   > adding and removing collaborators, and managing permissions for Google
   > Cloud resources.
6. Using App Engine or/and Compute Engine depends on your use case and preferences:

   - For Compute Engine you can [reserve static external IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) (if needed), [create VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance) using them and [add required records](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/records) to zones.
   - For App Engine you can follow documentation [Mapping Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application), as it was suggested by *@N Singh*.

Please provide more details in your question or post a new one if you need more detailed instructions.